# How to draw over native Windows Explorer

Tags: java, windows-explorer

Tinkering around with Google Drive desktop application, I noticed, its sole UI is just a native Windows Explorer. The interesting part behind it, is the background process `(googledrivesync.exe)`, that constently checks if any changes had taken place in that folder. If any changes occured it will sync them with the online drive, ok.

What made me wonder, when you drop a file, a small status icon will be painted over the file's own icon:

[image: regular Google Drive snapshot]

Now, this is not a one-time draw - I noticed. Look, If you change the view to large tiles the size of the icons also get larger:

[image: large-tile Google Drive snapshot]

It can't be that it registers the icon, somewhere in the - say - Registry Editor, or so; because, if I force to stop the processes (by Task Manager) and refresh the Explorer, they disappear. That gives me the feeling that it is a real-time paint.

This made me really curious, *'Does it really check if I change my view, or maybe there's a clean (native) way to accomplish this? And how?'*.

Although this could've been asked on any language, I chose Java, because that's what I use.

Comment: As you said, it's *native*, so plain java can't do that. I don't know if there already is a native library which adds the support for this functionality, likely you'll have to play with JNI/JNA to accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah, but I still want to understand the semantics behind, otherwise I can't reproduce it even with JNI support.

Comment: Imho small icons are added with shell overlay icon handlers.